# Why my delete test method can not find User with id 7?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am developing an app where I have to write test for my code. I am writing a test for my UserService class. This is my UserService class:

```
 private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("userLogger");

    @EJB
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public List<User> list() {
        LOG.info("Get all users!");
        return Optional.ofNullable(userDAO.findAll())
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream().map(u -> u.toUser())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(long id) {
        UserEntity userEntity = userDAO.find((id));
        if (userEntity == null) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(id);
        }
        LOG.info("User founded with id {}", id);
        return userEntity.toUser();
    }

    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new ServiceException("Invalid request!");
        }
        UserEntity exists = userDAO.find(user.getId());
        if (exists != null) {
            throw new UserAlreadyExistsException(user.getId());
        }
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity(user);

        userDAO.create(userEntity);
        LOG.info("Created user with id {}. Username is {}. Name is {}. Surname is {}. Email is {}.",
                userEntity.getUserId(), userEntity.getUsername(), userEntity.getName(),
                userEntity.getSurname(), userEntity.getEmail());
        return userEntity.toUser();
    }

    @Override
    public User update(long id, User user) {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new ServiceException("Invalid request!");
        }
        UserEntity userEntity = userDAO.find((id));
        if (userEntity == null) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(id);
        }
        userEntity.update(user);
        userDAO.update(userEntity);
        return userEntity.toUser();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(long id) {
        UserEntity userEntity = userDAO.find(id);
        if (userEntity == null) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException(id);
        }
        userDAO.delete(userEntity);
        LOG.info("Deleted user with id {}", userEntity.getUserId());
    }

}
```

This is my test class:

```
private static User useric;
    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    UserService userService;

    @Mock
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        UserEntity userEntity = mock(UserEntity.class);
        willReturn(mock(User.class)).given(userEntity).toUser();
        //willReturn(userEntity).given(userDAO).find(0L);
        useric = new User(7, "DDD", "SDSDS", "SAAsd", "qwqwqw@gmail.com");

    }

    @Test
    public void testWhenUserExist() throws Exception {
        //User goran = new User(5, "goran1992", "goran", "palibrk", "palibrk.goran@gmail.com");
        //User user = userService.create(goran);
        // GIVEN
        User user = userService.create(useric);
        //long userId = 0;

        // WHEN
       // user = userService.findById(goran.getId());

        // THEN
        assertNotNull(user);
        Assert.assertEquals(7, user.getId());
        //verify(userService, Mockito.times(1)).findById(userId);



    }

    @Test(expectedExceptions = ServiceException.class, expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "user-service: User with id: 35 was not found!")
    public void testWhenUserNotExist() throws Exception {
        // GIVEN
        long userId = 35;

        // WHEN
        userService.findById(userId);

        // THEN
        fail();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() throws Exception{
        User user = userService.create(useric);
        assertNotNull(user);
        Assert.assertEquals(useric.getName(), user.getName());
        //User userEntity = new User(1, "aaaewwe", "bbbb", "abba", "asa@gmail.com");
        //User user = userService.create(userEntity);
        // Assert.assertEquals(user, user);
        //assertNotNull(user);
       // Assert.assertEquals(userEntity, user);
       // verify(userService, Mockito.times(1)).create(userEntity);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeleteUser() throws Exception{

        User user = userService.create(useric);
        userService.findById(user.getId());
        userService.delete(user.getId());
        //verify(userService, Mockito.times(1)).delete(useric.getId());
    }
```

And when I run this test, I have this error:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\pgoran\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1992695267\testng-customsuite.xml

[main] INFO userLogger - Created user with id 7. Username is DDD. Name is SAAsd. Surname is SDSDS. Email is qwqwqw@gmail.com.
[main] INFO userLogger - Created user with id 7. Username is DDD. Name is SAAsd. Surname is SDSDS. Email is qwqwqw@gmail.com.
[main] INFO userLogger - Created user with id 7. Username is DDD. Name is SAAsd. Surname is SDSDS. Email is qwqwqw@gmail.com.
PASSED: testCreateUser
PASSED: testWhenUserExist
PASSED: testWhenUserNotExist
FAILED: testDeleteUser
com.comtrade.trips.service.user.exception.UserNotFoundException: user-service: User with id: 7 was not found!
    at com.comtrade.trips.service.user.UserService.findById(UserService.java:45)
    at com.comtrade.trips.service.user.UserServiceImplementationTest.testDeleteUser(UserServiceImplementationTest.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@7fc229ab: 18 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 17 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@27ae2fd0: 68 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@15b204a1: 11 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@56a6d5a6: 9 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@45b9a632: 33 ms
```

I see that my error is that could not find user with id=7 but I dont know how when I created user with that id in line above in delete method.
The question is, how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public void delete(long id) {
>     UserEntity userEntity = userDAO.find(id);
> ```

your `userDAO` is a mock which is not configured to return something for ID 7, therefor it returns a `null`

add

```
willReturn(userEntity).given(userDAO).find(7L);
```

to the `//Given` part of your test